# EDGE API custom annotation implementation

Tags: guidewire

Below are the details of the situation :

1. Existing GW PC typelist has 2 TypeFilters
2. Need to conditionally invoke(based on form type/form number ... pulled from CONTEXT) the @FilterBy annotation in DTO layer ... so that, particular set of data is displayed in GW PE for different combination of form type/form number.
3. We tried with @FilterByCustomAnnotation(Valdiation.getContext("FORMTYPE")) ... unfortunately, the return type of Valdiation.getContext() is ExpressionDTO and we are unable to convert it to String.

Requesting help in designing custom annotation to take the FORMNUMBER from CONTEXT --> convert/parse the data to String --> call OOTB function getState() and pass _filterName variable to ValidationRuleDTO

Comment: There have been some changes in Edge validations over the years.  Which version are you using?  @FilterByCustomAnnotation is not in the current cloud codebase.

Comment: we are using V10.2.1

Comment: That sounds like the PC version and a Self-Managed version.   What version of  Edge are you using?